# ng-select is not working along with a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a plunker in order to emphasize the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QHUpCv?p=preview

If I remove the custom attribute, or move the `ng-select` out of it, the companies are listed as the should, in case I use ng select with or within the custom attribute directive that I have created it breaks.

I suspect that some kind of `$watch` is required there inside of the scope for `menuCtrl`, but I have no idea whatsoever how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can tell, the problem is that you are generating a new scope for your directive, so a quick fix would be to forbid that via:

```
// [...]
restrict: "A",
scope: false,
link: //..
```

I made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yOjmeU?p=preview) here to illustrate.

If you do want it this way and prefer an own scope for this directive, you can pass in the values for the select, i.e.

```
<div restrict companies="companies" access="admin">
```

and read it in in the `scope`of the directive:

```
restrict: 'A',
prioriry: 100000,
scope: {
  companies: '='
},
```

of course, you would then use the companies directly with the select:

```
<select ng-model="data.selectedCompany" ng-options="company for (id, company) in companies">
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly fine now!
Can you please specify more about the second part of your answer? or perhaps refer me to a written source of some kind?.

Also passing the handler function as a parameter seems to me like awful monkey patching, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Well, i'd start here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope. As for the handler function - i'd not do that and just let the service return me the `promise`for the data and then apply the handler directly in the controller

Comment: Cam you please provide a code sample?
I am very new to angular, do you need me to open a separate question for that?.
Making the declarative pars of angular dependent of XHR requests is not well documented at all!

Comment: Thanks! also, I almost forgot, I am interested in using several directive as this one per each view, meaning that an isolate scope is indeed necessary!.

Comment: Also, for convenience purposes, I would like to use this directive on a container element, and to remove all of it's children and the element it self in case that the role of the current user doesn't have the sufficient privileges to view the content of this element.
The idea is to build an SPA which displays different features in each view depending on the role of the user

Comment: That seems a bit more complex than what i can provide in the short time I have, you'll probably have to fiddle around a bit for yourself (and for specific questions use SA). Anyways, here ya go: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dr4GBhQrI0GIeoQUxlUy

Comment: Well, apparently it is working, I haven't tested all of the cases just yet, but I will keep you posted!
Thanks!